# Popup does not open/close into an Ajax request using JQuery 1.4.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, popup

I'm trying to show a dinamic popup using Javascript/JQuery (1.4.5), into an Ajax Request, like this:

```
function ingresar(){


    var username = $('#user').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: [myurl],
         data: {name:username, pass:password},
         beforeSend: function(){
             $("#emergente").popup('open'); //does not works
         },
         complete: function(){
             /*$("#emergente").popup('close'); //does not works..*/
             document.getElementById("emergente").style.display = "none";
          },
          success: function (data) {
             //Some code here
          },
          error: function (err) {
             //Some code here
          }
    });
}
```

but, When I run the code, the web view throws the following error:

```
$(...).popup is not a function.
```

I've imported Jquery-ui scripts in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"  href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"  href="css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"  href="css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" />
```

And here is my html div page:

```
<div id="paginauno" data-role="page" data-theme='b'>
   <div data-role="content" align="center">
     <form id="formulario">
      <!-- user and passw fields -->
      <button id="botoningresar" type="submit" class="ui-btn" onclick="ingresar()" >
         <span class="etiqueta">Ingresar<span>
      </button>
     </form>
   </div>
   <div id="emergente" data-role="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="turn">
      <div align="center">
         <img src="img/loader.gif" />
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've worked for a long time in this, but I've could not with It.

I've seen the following links, but neither has worked me.
[Jquery Mobile 1.4.5 Popup not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950988/jquery-mobile-1-4-5-popup-not-working)
[JQuery-mobile. Can't open the dialog programmatically; tried everything I could think of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071669/jquery-mobile-cant-open-the-dialog-programmatically-tried-everything-i-could)

I've tried to load "ingresar" function on page create event of the document like this:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate",function(){
  $("#botoningresar").on("click",function(){ingresar();});
});
```

but did not works. Does anyone have any idea?
The final target is show a custom window, that shows an animated progress using gif file and not JQueryMobile progress default, when the "ingresar" button is pressed.

Comment: Originally I had posted a comment - since deleted - asking if you imported jQuery (core), but it looks like you did, as it's in the header to your question, and would explain the error message not stating $ is not a function; however, it looks like you may have left our jQuery Mobile, which is where the `popup` function comes from.

Comment: Hi mark.hch, yes. The JQuery mobile scripts there are imported in the header. Thanks, anyway.